# What does the Mayavi contour3d docs mean when it refers to "the arrows"?

Tags: python, mayavi

I understand how to plot contours for a grid of data in mayavi like this:

```
from mayavi import mlab
mlab.contour3d(my_data_grid)
```

However, I'm curious what this other signature for the function is:

```
mlab.contour3d(x, y, z, my_data_grid)
```

The [docs](http://docs.enthought.com/mayavi/mayavi/auto/mlab_helper_functions.html#contour3d) say:

> If 4 arrays, (x, y, z, scalars) are passed, the 3 first arrays give
>   the position of the arrows, and the last the scalar value.

What are "the arrows"? I haven't found any examples and when I try to call it with my dataset I get a segfault so haven't been able to test.

EDIT: Well now I understand the format that mlab expects x, y, and z in and I was able to get it to work. However, there were no arrows! I'm assuming this is an error in the documentation...

Answer (score 1):

It is not so much an error in the documentation, but more of a seemingly awkward way to describe the function. From the same document, `contour3d`:

> Plots iso-surfaces for a 3D volume of data supplied as arguments

and it is stated that (bolding mine):

> The x, y and z arrays are then supposed to have been generated by numpy.mgrid, **in other words, they are 3D arrays, with positions lying on a 3D orthogonal and regularly spaced grid** with nearest neighbor in space matching nearest neighbor in the array. The function builds a scalar field assuming the points are regularly spaced.

The 'arrows' seem to be a somewhat awkward way of saying that `x`, `y` and `z` are `

> 3D arrays, with positions lying on a 3D orthogonal and regularly
>   spaced grid

with the function 'building a scalar field' as an iso-surface, effectively 'connecting the dots (positions)'.